# Access temp files on iOS app with an expired certificate

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

the project I'm working on was initially distributed signed with an enterprise certificate and ad-hoc installations (meaning, NO APP STORE).

Problem is now that this certificate has expired, and we need to retrieve some temporary files from within this app folder on two devices. Usually, I just use xCode to download app's file system and I'm done. Trouble now is that it won't let me do that (I'm guessing because of the expired certificate).

Do you guys know any workaround to bypass this and access app's filesystem?

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to retrieve these files:

1. Installed iExplorer
2. Made a backup using XCode on my mac
3. Opened that backup using iExplorer
4. Copied files from the backup to my mac

Hope this helps someone.